# how to fix this little bad URI(is not URI?) error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri, httparty

i need to interpolate a variable into my url, i have tried everything i have found (using the open uri method open(), also using URI()) but nothing seems to work.

```
  def self.find(id)
    HTTParty.get("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/#{id}.json", format: :json)
  end
```

The variable that i need to interpolate is id.
Thanks a lot for reading.

Comment: Try `puts "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/#{id}.json"` and see what is the output ?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/[:id].json @Shiko

Comment: try to print the id only alone. `puts id`

Comment: hmm weird printing id gives [:id]

Comment: it seems you are sending Symbol and not value.

Comment: yea, that was it thanks a million

Comment: exactly this is the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are sending **sybmol** and not value. Verify the function calling **Find** method and assure it is value and not symbol.